How to put two images, left and right aligned in header in a word file (.docx) Python
I want to put two logo images in the header of the document. One logo should stay at the very left and the other at the very right of the word file. Below is my code, but this sets both logos on the right side, one after the other.
from docx import Document

document = Document()
section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header

paragraph_1 = header.paragraphs[0]
paragraph_1.alignment = 1  
logo_run_1 = paragraph_1.add_run()
logo_run_1.add_picture("uv_logo.png", width=Cm(5))
last_picture = header.paragraphs[-1] 
last_picture.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT

paragraph_2 = header.paragraphs[0]
paragraph_1.alignment = 2  # Right aligned
logo_run_2 = paragraph_1.add_run()
logo_run_1.add_picture("fm_logo.png", width=Cm(5))
last_picture = logo_run_2._element
last_picture = header.paragraphs[-1] 
last_picture.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT


So far, python-docx only supports inline images. These have no alignment. Consider them as characters in text.
So imagine your requirement like this:
"[PICTURE_uv_logo.png][white space][PICTURE_fm_logo.png]"

The white space may be multiple space characters or may be tabs. Fortunately the first header paragraph has two default tab stops. One is at center and performs alignment WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.CENTER. The other is at right and performs performs alignment WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT. So we can do something like:
"[PICTURE_uv_logo.png]\t\t[PICTURE_fm_logo.png]"

The code could look like so:
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm

document = Document()
section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header

paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
#Paragraph in header has two default tab stops.
#One is at center and WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.CENTER.
#The other is at right and WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT.

logo_run_1 = paragraph.add_run()
logo_run_1.add_picture("uv_logo.png", width=Cm(5)) #this is at left

tab_run = paragraph.add_run()
tab_run.add_tab() # jumps to center/CENTER
tab_run.add_tab() # jumps to right/RIGHT

logo_run_2 = paragraph.add_run()
logo_run_2.add_picture("fm_logo.png", width=Cm(5)) #this is at right

document.save('test.docx')


you can add a table with one row and two columns for left and right alignment.
For eg.
from docx import Document

table = header.add_table(rows=1, cols=2, width=Cm(16)) 

table.columns[0].width = Cm(8)
table.columns[1].width = Cm(8)

cell_left = table.cell(0, 0)
cell_right = table.cell(0, 1)

paragraph_left = cell_left.paragraphs[0]
paragraph_left.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
run_left = paragraph_left.add_run()
run_left.add_picture("uv_logo.png", width=Cm(5))

paragraph_right = cell_right.paragraphs[0]
paragraph_right.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
run_right = paragraph_right.add_run()
run_right.add_picture("fm_logo.png", width=Cm(5))

document.save("header_with_logos.docx")

